# getopts passing value of declared parameter to function

Tags: bash, shell-script, getopts

I have function `port.sh` as stand alone script and i'm wondering if is possible to put this function in the same script where getopts is
and pass value of `OPT_B` into function and get output of it?

```
        OPT_B=B

        while getopts :a FLAG; do
          case $FLAG in
            b)  #set option "b"
             OPT_B=$OPTARG
              ;;
          esac
        done

    shift $((OPTIND-1))

!!-->> port $1 <<--!! -> OPT_B=$(port $1) ??

    function port()
     {
        if  [ "$1" = 'B' ]; then
        set $1=8000
        echo "declared value: $1"

        elif [[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && [ "$1" -ge 1 -a "$1" -le 10000 ]; then
        echo "chosen value: $1"
        else echo "chosen value $1 is not in '1 - 10000'"
        fi
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You are only telling getopts to look for a flag `-a`, not `-b`. Fix that (`getopts :ab: ...`) then use `port "$OPT_B"`

Comment: Also his line: `set $1=8000` sets the first positional parameter ($1) to the value "B=8000". This only takes effect for the duration of the function. If you want to use this value later in the script, use `OPT_B=8000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `function port()` - it doesn't actually make any sense. When declaring a `bash` or `ksh` function with the `function` command you don't use the `()` but the shell accepts it as a forgivable syntax oops and acts like you didn't use `function` at all. So don't.

```
port()
    case ${1:--} in (B) OPT_B=8000;; (*[!0-9]*)
     !   printf 'chosen value %s not in %s\n' \
                "${1:-''}" "'1 - 10000'"      ;;
    (*)  [ "$(( $1>0 && $1<10001 ))" -ne 0 ]  &&
         echo "chosen value '$1'"             ||
         port "'$1'"                          ;;
    esac
```

That is a POSIXly correct way to write your function *(except that the above returns correctly in the event of an error)*. If the above were in a shell script other than `$0` and I wanted to call that function anyway, I would probably do:

```
eval "$(sed '/^port()/,$!d;/esac/q' /path/to/script_containing_port.sh)" 
port B #or whatever
```

...if I could be sure that the first occurrence of `^port()` in that script definitely signified the beginning of the function I wanted to declare. Else, if the function were in a script all its own, I would do:

```
. /path/to/port.fn.sh; port B
```

Last, you probably shouldn't name your script files *something.sh* unless they really are `sh` scripts - which is to say, if you write a `bash` script name it `something.bash`. It doesn't make sense otherwise.